# There's no column 'UserID' but i have that column

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

Why i don't have a column `UserID` but i already have?
[This is my Database for proof that i have UserID colum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djUWU.png)

Here is the code.

```
private void StudentForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentuser = labelGetCurrentUserID.Text;

    DataTable dataTable = LoadDataFromDatabase(currentuser);
    dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"UserID = '{currentuser}'";

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
}

public DataTable LoadDataFromDatabase (string GetcurrnetID)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    

    using (OleDbConnection Getconnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionStrings))
    {
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();

        Getconnection.Open();
        string userId = labelGetCurrentUserID.Text;

        cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [UserID] FROM TblLogs WHERE UserID = @UserID", connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userId);

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(datatable);
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

I was trying to filter the current logged in user and display in dataGridView based on their user ID.

Comment: If you are filtering in the query, then there is no point applying the filter in the default view

Comment: @ChrisSchaller so what should it do?

Comment: If you are filtering in the view, DO NOT filter in the OleDbCommand. Or atleast filter on a different criteria. In your case, because you are filtering in the OleDbCommand, do not apply a filter in the default view... Of course if both filters are the same, there is no problem, but having two places to apply the filter is going to complicate your debugging process until you understand this code a lot more

Comment: If you don't set the `RowFilter`, then what do you see in `dataGridView1` after the DataSource is set?